# How is database protected from queries which can fill up memory on database server?

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb

I understand that we need to use cursors when the number of records in database is massive and can fill up memory on app and database server.
However if someone does not use cursors and selects all the records in a massive table:

1. How does database server protect itself from exhausting the memory ? eg: is per query memory capped ?
2. How does application server protect itself from exhausting memory and preventing OOO exceptions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only interface between the server and the driver for retrieving result sets is cursor-based. The driver *always* uses cursors.

If an application "does not use cursors", what that typically means is the application iterates cursors to completion and loads the entire result set into memory. This doesn't affect memory usage on the server - it only increases memory usage in the application processes.

> How does database server protect itself from exhausting the memory ? eg: is per query memory capped ?

There are various memory limits on various operations, such as sorting, to ensure memory usage is not unbounded.

> How does application server protect itself from exhausting memory and preventing OOO exceptions ?

Typically by not loading entire result sets into memory, though given the wider variety of tasks in applications it is more likely for an average application to use a lot of memory than it would be for an average database.